# Is there an elegant solution to calling a struct's mutating method from another mutating method?

Tags: rust

I have a struct and method like this:

```
pub struct S {
    a: Vec<u32>,
    b: Vec<u32>,
}

impl S {
    // Pretend that this function has a similar signature but an
    // implementation that is much more complicated and verbose
    fn b_index_mut(&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut u32 {
        &mut self.b[i]
    }

    pub fn foo(&mut self) {
        for (i, x) in self.a.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            *self.b_index_mut(i) += *x;
        }
    }
}
```

`S.foo()` will not compile:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:15:14
   |
14 |         for (i, x) in self.a.iter_mut().enumerate() {
   |                       ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
15 |             *self.b_index_mut(i) += *x;
   |              ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
16 |         }
   |         - first borrow ends here
```

There is this possible implementation which eliminates this error by simply moving the body of `S.b_index_mut()` into `S.foo()`:

```
impl S {
    pub fn foo(&mut self) {
        for (i, x) in self.a.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            self.b[i] += *x;
        }
    }
}
```

However, as I said in the comment in the first implementation, the real `S.b_index_mut()` that I have in mind is much more verbose that the example, and it is really something that should have its own function.

A possible work around is to pass `b` as an argument to `S.b_index_mut()`:

```
impl S {
    // Pretend that this function has a similar signature but an
    // implementation that is much more complicated and verbose
    fn b_index_mut(b: &mut Vec<u32>, i: usize) -> &mut u32 {
        &mut b[i]
    }

    pub fn foo(&mut self) {
        for (i, x) in self.a.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            *S::b_index_mut(&mut self.b, i) += *x;
        }
    }
}
```

This solution compiles and solves the abstraction problem. However, it seems inelegant. Something feels wrong to me about calling a struct function that doesn't take `self` for anything other than a constructor.

If the real version of `S.b_index_mut()` requires factoring in more members of `S` (that are not `a`), just writing the function call itself can become quite verbose.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: [Move all of the relevant variables to a new struct, move the method to that struct, then embed the new struct in your existing one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=059fa974e0d1570d12b65b875d2b6ec5&version=stable). That's your "real" abstraction, anyway.